# Vegetarian food in Cala Mayor Beach, Spain

Tags: food-and-drink, spain

I'm visiting Cala Mayor Beach in Palma de Mallorca island in June and was wondering if it is very vegetarian friendly? The reason I ask is, upon flipping through all the pictures of restaurants all I can seem to find is fish and seafood everywhere! Though being a island, I guess they would want to show this off.

Comment: Yup, Mallorca (or Majorca).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being vegetarian in Spain is very difficult, if you stay here for a long time - cook by yourself, the selection of vegetables is very good, prices are low and quality is perfect. Also check for Moroccan and oriental restaurants - they have some selection of chickpeas dishes.

PS: Good selection of vegetables at markets doesn't mean that you will have tasty vegan dishes in the restaurants. My piscarian wife ordered several times fish that was carefully wrapped into perfect jamon slices. So, always double check with waiter about the dish "sin carne, soy vegetariano".

Comment: Good selection of veggies doesn't mean that you will have only veggies selection in restaurants. Common Spanish dish is beans + pork in varieties of spices of local flavors.

Comment: @pnuts I think they are using the American English meaning of veggies = vegetables, as opposed to the British/commonwealth of veggies = vegetarians/vegetarian food.  Probably worth an edit.

Comment: every day is a lesson )

Comment: "*Sin carne*" is not enough to get vegetarian food. I've seen waiters interpret it as "*I don't eat beef*" and think that it doesn't apply to ham, chicken, fish...

Answer (score 4):

A quick search by "cala mayor beach vegetarian food" on [Google](http://www.google.com) gave me 2 [restaurants](http://www.mallorca-now.com/restaurants-mallorca.html) that offer vegetarian food. *QCUTE CHAT SHOP* (they serve *organic ingredients and vegetarian dishes are available*) and *PLAER NATURAL RESTAURANT* (serving *vegetarian restaurant, organic produce*).
Never been to any of them, but it seems that vegetarian food is available in Cala Mayor Beach.